# Fortran breadth first search running slowly

Tags: performance, fortran, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

**Background:**
I have written a Fortran subroutine which computes the shortest path length matrix from an adjacency matrix for an unweighted, directed network. The subroutine uses a breadth first search algorithm. The diagonal elements of the shortest path length matrix are the shortest loop lengths.

I have also implemented this algorithm in MATLAB. I am migrating to Fortran in the hope of reducing run times (note that I am new to Fortran). However, this subroutine runs marginally faster in MATLAB than it does in the Fortran implementation (~44 seconds in MATLAB vs ~46 seconds in Fortran for the same ~1000 node network). This does not make sense to me because my understanding is that Fortran should be significantly faster for loop based operations. Some of my other subroutines are 1-2 orders of magnitude faster in Fortran.

I am compiling on OSX 10.10.2 with the latest gfortran binaries installed and no optimisation flags. (Turning the optimisation flags on actually seems to slow the code down further.)

**Question:**
Can anyone see flaws in my fortan code that could be making it run inefficiently? (Any other general tips for a Fortran newbie would be appreciated as well). Alternatively, is there a faster algorithm for this task?

**Code:**

```
subroutine spl(a,splmat)
implicit none

! Input: Adjacency matrix a
logical, intent(in) :: a(:,:)

! Output: Shortest path length matrix
integer, dimension (:,:), allocatable :: splmat

integer, dimension (:), allocatable :: stk

! Variables: nnodes (size of network); s (source node); r (read ptr);
! w (write pointer) ; d (distance from s to node n), n (the node
! pointed to by the value of the stack at r); j (loop variable);
integer :: nnodes,s,r,w,d,n,j

nnodes = size(a,1)

allocate(splmat(nnodes,nnodes))
splmat = 0

allocate (stk(nnodes))

! Outer loop over each node
do s = 1,nnodes
    stk = 0
    stk(1) = s
    r = 1
    w = 2

    ! Inner loop
    do while (r/=w)
        n = stk(r)
        r = r+1

        d = splmat(s,n)

        do j=1,nnodes
            if (a(n,j).and.(splmat(s,j)==0)) then
                splmat(s,j) = d+1
                stk(w) = j
                w = w+1
            end if
        end do
    end do
end do
end subroutine spl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the algorithm you are using, but one very simple problem I noticed immediately is that your indices are in the wrong order for best performance in Fortran.

What I mean is that this is typically not good:

```
do i = 1, m
    do j = 1, n
        ! Do something with a(i,j)
    end do
end do
```

Whereas this is much better:

```
do j = 1, n
    do i = 1, m
        ! Do something with a(i,j)
    end do
end do
```

For small problems there is typically not much difference (except in certain cases where you are relying heavily on SIMD vectorization for performance). However for larger problems there can be a big difference in the efficiency of cache usage.

Comment: Thanks Sean! That solved the problem. I had a read about column-major order and that all makes sense. By changing the loop order the code run time reduced to ~14 seconds. Furthermore, optimising with the -O3 flag reduced the time to ~4.5 seconds which is 10x better than my original fortran code and my old MATLAB code. For anyone else out there looking for information on column-major ordering there are some basic pointers and examples here: [link](http://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/FORTRAN/Intel10/doc/main_for/mergedProjects/optaps_for/fortran/optaps_prg_arrs_f.htm)